How can I create a new vsplit to the left of the topmost window with the same height with only commands?
Let's say I have two windows on the top and bottom, full width. I want to create a new window to the left of the top one and the same height. If there are two windows on the top taking up half width each, I would want the window to be on the far left and then have all three top windows be equal width.

This command move to the top window and creates wincmd t | aboveleft vnew.
I found this documentation:
    :leftabove {cmd}    left or above the current window
    :aboveleft {cmd}    idem
    :rightbelow {cmd}   right or below the current window
    :belowright {cmd}   idem
    :topleft {cmd}      at the top or left of the Vim window
    :botright {cmd}     at the bottom or right of the Vim window


The two problems:

1 top window -> 2 top windows, new one on the left,
2 top windows -> 3 top windows, new one on the left,

are fundamentally identical, and solved the same way:

Move the cursor to the top-left window.
Do :vnew if :help 'splitright' is off (default) or :leftabove vnew if it is on. The latter being more deterministic than the former, but also more verbose.

See :help windows for more.
