Is it possible to run a command on a specific buffer without switching to it?
A command to run on a buffer given its number or titled printed in :ls. This doesn't seem to be possible with :bufdo.

You mean an ex-command? Or something like a operating system command?

@ChristianBrabandt OP's previous question for context: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/44742/how-can-i-create-a-new-vsplit-to-the-left-of-the-topmost-window-with-the-same-he

No. There is no such thing.

@romainl I already figured out that other question. This is separate.

Fwiw if the buffer is opened in a window you can use win_execute()

The closest you can get is probably simulation via (:help text-functions)
Working with text in another buffer:
    getbufline()        get a list of lines from the specified buffer
    getbufoneline()     get a one line from the specified buffer
    setbufline()        replace a line in the specified buffer
    appendbufline()     append a list of lines in the specified buffer
    deletebufline()     delete lines from a specified buffer

Many functions take a {bufnr}, but generally Vim assumes you're editing the current buffer.
